# Application only crashes on start when run on TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, sprite, testflight

Currently I have an iOS app which I plan to release for beta testing. My problem is that the app will not run as after 2 seconds or so after the app has shown the `GameScene.swift SKScene`, it crashes and it keeps on repeating.

I have compiled the app via `Xcode 7.3` in both `Release` and `Debug` configurations. I have analysed the project, cleaned it, uninstalled it, reinstalled it, restored my device etc. But nothing changes. This unexpected crash only happens when the app is run via `TestFlight`. I will attach below the log from the crashes. I have tried to symbolicate the crash but it just shows up the original log file.

```
 Incident Identifier: 408B1212-4AE8-42E2-905F-D4567D5030AD
 CrashReporter Key:   4c7013cab29b9011557c3005550950488452cc04
 Hardware Model:      xxx
 Process:             Number Tap [2226]
 Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/69833BAF-AD19-4FAF-BB95-E766A493D525/Number Tap.app/Number Tap
 Identifier:          com.flatboxstudio.numbertap
 Version:             2 (1.0.1)
 Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
 Parent Process:      launchd [1]

 Date/Time:           2016-03-29 18:44:31.31 -0700
 Launch Time:         2016-03-29 18:44:31.31 -0700
 OS Version:          iOS 9.3 (13E233)
 Report Version:      105

 Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
 Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100046724
 Triggered by Thread:  0

 Filtered syslog:
 None found

 Breadcrumb Trail: (reverse chronological seconds)
 0      GC Framework: startAuthenticationForExistingPrimaryPlayer


 Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
 Thread 0 Crashed:
 0   Number Tap                     0x0000000100046724 0x10000c000 + 239396
 1   libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018200d4bc 0x18200c000 + 5308
 2   libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018200d47c 0x18200c000 + 5244
 3   libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000182012b84 0x18200c000 + 27524
 4   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182578dd8 0x182498000 + 921048
 5   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182576c40 0x182498000 + 912448
 6   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001824a0d10 0x182498000 + 36112
 7   GraphicsServices               0x0000000183d88088 0x183d7c000 + 49288
 8   UIKit                          0x000000018776df70 0x1876f0000 + 515952
 9   Number Tap                     0x0000000100046bdc 0x10000c000 + 240604
 10  libdyld.dylib                  0x000000018203e8b8 0x18203c000 + 10424

 Activity ID:             0x0000000000043e33
 Activity Name:           starting resolver activity
 Activity Image Path:     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
 Activity Image UUID:     A1D92752-ABF1-3834-9EBB-FE35E00EB642
 Activity Offset:         0x0003333c
 Activity Running Time:   0.468516 sec

 Trace Messages (reverse chronological seconds):
 0.292098     GameCenterFoundation          0x000000019066a20c authenticateWithCompletionHandler:Username and Password passed in. GKDaemonProxy to authenticate player
 0.296164     CFNetwork                     0x0000000204da9da8 Format not found
 0.300431     CFNetwork                     0x0000000204da9da8 Format not found
 0.301584     CFNetwork                     0x0000000204da9da8 Format not found
 0.301623     CFNetwork                     0x0000000182c493a8 TCP Conn 0x146553ea0 started
 0.305076     CFNetwork                     0x0000000182ca3ce8 Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
 0.305077     CFNetwork                     0x0000000182ca3cb4 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
 0.305077     CFNetwork                     0x0000000182cf5e44 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
```

I removed some of the log as I felt it may be unimportant. I have read apples guide on resolving this but still not resolved.I will be truly grateful if anybody could help me out. If you need any extra code, logs or information don't hesitate to ask. (The whole log was quite long so I cropped some information out.)

Comment: Have you [symbolicated the crash report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/)? The dSYM file should be inside the xcarchive file that was created before you submitted it to TestFlight.

Comment: As mentioned I tried that but it didn't work for me, it showed the same thing. Im still trying to see if I can get that working.

Comment: This is what I entered in terminal  `atos -arch armv7 -o Number\ Tap.app/Number\ Tap 0x00000001000e6724`

And this was my responce `0x00000001000e6724` the same thing

Comment: Try `atos -arch arm64 -o Number\ Tap.app/Number\ Tap -l 0x10000c000 0x0000000100046724`. The crash is for `arm64`, the binary is loaded at `0x10000c000`, and the crash is at address `0x0000000100046724`.

Comment: This was my result `0x000000010003a724 (in Number Tap) + 1292`

Comment: Is the dSYM for this build in the same directory as you run the command?

Comment: yes my dSYM is there. I added it again but still the same responce. Ill attach a screenshot of my files - http://imgur.com/kt4QQAg